# Create a SocksPort with fix circuit/greater MaxCircuitDirtiness

Tags: configuration

For all my applications I am happy with the 10 min `MaxCircuitDirtiness` - it shall not change.
But there is one application that needs the same IP for multiple requests (more than 10 min apart).

I thought I could generate a new `SocksPort` for that specific purpose but I would need to adapt the `MaxCircuitDirtiness` for that Port only. Is that possible or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on debian or ubuntu, you may use [tor-instance-create](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/tor/tor-instance-create.8.en.html) to create another instance which you can configure (in a different file for that instance) according to your needs.